# No aparecen mis imagenes en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

En un Proyecto en Laravel, quiero cargar una imagen.

Así

```
 <img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/'. $pet->image) }}">
```

Ya que las imagenes están en la capeta public

Pero, me dice esto

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

la imagen está, el path está bien, pero por alguna razón como que no reconoce la carpeta images,

```
images:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/images 404 (Not Found)
```

debería decir  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/1.png`

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 1):

Según veo estas intentando hacer esta carga:

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/'. $pet->image) }}">
```

El asunto de recibir el error es porque estas intentando cargar una carpeta en la ruta de una imagen, pues al parecer tu problema esta en la carga de la info.

Debes verificar que esta variable este trayendo la información o nombre de la imagen a mostrar:

```
$pet->image
```

Prueba colocandola manualmente a ver si te da el mismo error:

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/1.png') }}">
```

También te recomiendo para trabajar el servidor local Laragon que es perfecto para desarrollos con Laravel entre otras cosas.